# Insert and admin only page in my registration/login code

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I got my registration/login code for my website working today.

Now I want to let my login recognize if someone logs in with an admin account, so he can be redirected to the admin page.  My table is called "klanten" en it has the columns:

```
fldVoornaam(varchar), fldNaam(varchar), fldPassword, fldEmail(varchar), admin(boolean)
```

So I manually put admin users a value of 1, and rest gets default 0 in the admin column, now I want to check when the user logs in with his email and password, that he is and admin or not, and will get redirected to the right page.

This is what I got:

```
<?php
require('db.php');
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_POST['submitLogin'])){
    $fldEmail = $_POST['fldEmail'];
    $fldPassword = $_POST['fldPassword'];
    $fldEmail = stripslashes($fldEmail);
    $fldEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $fldEmail);
    $fldPassword = stripslashes($fldPassword);
    $fldPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $fldPassword);
//Checking is user existing in the database or not
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `klanten` WHERE fldEmail='$fldEmail' and fldPassword='".md5($fldPassword)."' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['fldEmail'] = $fldEmail;
        header("Location: login.php"); // redirect user to login
        }else{
            echo "<p class=\"warning\"><span class=\"fa fa-warning\"></span>password of emailadres dat u heb ingevuld is niet juist, probeer opnieuw.<span class=\"fa fa-warning\"></span></p>";
            }
}else{
?>
<div class="formLogin">
<p class="opening">Onze promoties voor klanten zijn enkel te zien als u zich inlogt</p>
<p class="opening">Log je nu in, of maak een <a class="registerlink" href="#formRegister">account</a> aan.<p>
<form action="" method="post" name="login" id="formLogin">
<input type="email" name="fldEmail" placeholder="Emailadres" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required />
<input type="password" id="test1" name="fldPassword" placeholder="password" pattern=".{6,}" title="6 of meer characters verplicht" required />
<div class="check"><input id="test2" type="checkbox"  /><label for="test2" class="checkbox">Show password</label></div>
<input name="submitLogin" type="submit" value="Login" id="submitLogin"/>
</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

And this is what I tried and not working:
https://gyazo.com/9c64c16db8a5960d5586cf9a9c8de49d

Kind regards,

Comment: Sidenote curiousity: Is this intended for a live site using that md5 hash?

Comment: No this is for my end project in school, could you elaborate why the mD5 hash is not good for a live website? i'd be happy to change it for the project if it is not good for security

Comment: Have a read => http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure it's all in there ;-) well, a good part of it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the result from your first query and see if the user is an admin or not:

```
$query = "SELECT fldEmail, admin FROM `klanten` WHERE fldEmail='$fldEmail' and fldPassword='".md5($fldPassword)."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rows==1){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)
    $_SESSION['fldEmail'] = $row[0]; //contains the email
    if($row[1] == 1) {
        // this user is an admin
    }

    header("Location: login.php"); // redirect user to login
    }else{
...
```